# Flow chart to program which count divided by 3

Tags: c#

I have to do flow chart to program which count is number is divided by 3.

I did code like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i, n, results;
    Console.WriteLine("Specify number of elements");
    n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    a = new int[n];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Specify number of element a[" + i + "]");
        a[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    results = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        results += a[i];
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Sum of elements is: " + results);

    if (results % 3 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number is divided by 3");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number isn't divided by 3");
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

and my flow chart look like in the attached photo:

[image]

Could you tell me is it correct?

Comment: please read [ask].  SO is not a code checking service - there are other sites where you can do that.  You need to have a specific question in mind that you need help with.   https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Follow what @TimRutter already stated. Also your question is ambiguous. You are not checking `i < m` anywhere and if `i = 0` it should return `"Number is divided by 3"`? why increment `i`?

Comment: Whilst this works, perhaps try something a bit slicker where you don't have to specify how many values are in the array to begin with. You could do the result as a running total and maybe just calculate if the user gives you a value that isn't an integer e.g return. Use Int.TryParse for that.

Comment: @RichardHousham I'm beginner in C#  so I'm not sure can I do running total but I'll try to do something with it. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flow diagrams are a bit well, tricky depends how much detail you want but here is what I would do. FYI I would use https://www.draw.io/ for diagrams it's free and pretty good.

[image]